# Creating PDF with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, pdf

I am using Zend Framework and inherited classes i.e. My_Pdf (that i got from sourceforge and My_Pdf library is used to draw tables)to create PDF file from database. When I create PDF file without table outlines it is working well and generating PDF. But when i try to draw table corresponding to data, I got an error,

```
Fatal error: Declaration of My_Pdf_Page::drawImage() must be compatible with that of  Zend_Pdf_Canvas_Interface::drawImage() in C:\Users\TranceServe\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace7\Crushed_PLanet\library\My\Pdf\Page.php on line 369
```

Please guide me what to do.

Comment: You have not accepted any answers so far! Please accept the best answer to each of your questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across this problem myself. I've not tested in 1.11.3, but in 1.11.0. All you have to do is change your method drawImage in My_Pdf_Page is specify the argument $image as being of object type 'Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image':

```
public function drawImage( Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image $image,$x1,$y1,$width,$height,$inContentArea=true){
```

Comment: I tried this one but now got another error on line where the script tried to create rows and cols..The error is **"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62 bytes)"**

Answer (score 5):

This means that the blueprint of a deriving class is not identical to a class higher up in the inheritance hiearchy.

And this most probably means that the PDF library has not been updated to work with the latest Zend Framework version.

You are using Zend Framework version 1.11.3 BUT...

[image]

Very obviously the library you are trying to use was written for Zend Framework 1.8 (first box), it has not been updated since May 2009 (second box) and therefore nobody downloads it anymore these days (third box).

Lesson: **Know your tools!**

Comment: You are right. I am using zend 8.0 and zend framework 1.11.3 .But don't know for which version this PDF library is written.As there was no description on the site

Comment: What do you mean with Zend 8. There is not such thing. Zend is a company. There is no 8th version of that company.

Comment: Post a link to that library in your question please!

Comment: zend 8 mean ide that i am using....anyway this is the link http://sourceforge.net/projects/zendpdftable/files/

Comment: The IDE is called Zend Studio.